# Add date if today is passed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2016

I have a date value in a cell.

So I want that if the date is today, return another cell value (still a date) and that it can do it again.

exemple :

```
A1 : 01/01/2019
B5 : 03/05/2019
B6 : 05/09/2019
B7 : 05/01/2020
B8 : 09/09/2021
```

if today is 01/01/2019 then return B5 value (03/05/2019)
and if today is 03/05/2019 return B6 value (05/09/2019)…

Comment: There's a worksheet function `=TODAY()`, which you can use for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula, i have tested it for the range B5:B8

```
=INDEX(B5:B8,MATCH(TODAY(),B5:B8,0)+1)
```

Remember that in order to test the functionality the range B5:B8 should have today's date present in it

**As per your comments this is the Edited version**

```
=INDEX(B5:B8,1+MAX(IF(TODAY()>B5:B8,MATCH(B5:B8,B5:B8,0),0)))
```

**Note** that it is an array formula. you have to press (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) after entering it in  the cell

It will work if the B5:B8 is in sorted ascending order. you can check it on your data and let me know if it working.

Comment: The excel file will not be opened every day... Maybe something like this ? IF the date in A1 is passed then value of A1 = B5. If value in A1 (B5 now then) is passed, then value of A1 = B6....

Comment: Are the date in B5:B8 always in sorted order?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `MATCH` and `OFFSET`.
Something like `=OFFSET(B4,MATCH(TODAY(),B4:B8,1),0)`
But you might need to add a *0 date* before the first date.

Comment: Something is wrong with this =DECALER(B4,EQUIV(AUJOURDHUI(),B4:B8,1),0)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
B5=IF(TODAY()=OFFSET($A$1,,),"03/05/2019","")
B6=IF(TODAY()=OFFSET($A$1,4,1),"05/09/2019","")
B7=IF(TODAY()=OFFSET($A$1,5,1),"05/01/2020","")
B8=IF(TODAY()=OFFSET($A$1,6,1),"09/09/2021","")
```

Results:
[image]